# Autoprefixer doesn’t support Node v0.10.48. Update it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5

initially i got this error-
Autoprefixer doesn’t support Node v0.10.48. Update it.
then 
i tried to add gem 'mini_racer' i am using centos server.
but when i run bundle i get this error

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/mini_racer-0.2.9/ext/mini_racer_extension
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby -I /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0 -r
./siteconf20200121-13084-vxv4tr.rb extconf.rb
checking for -lpthread... yes
<stdin>:2:5: error: #error A compiler that supports at least C++11 is required in order to compile this project.


WARNING: C++11 support is required for compiling mini_racer. Please make sure
you are using a compiler that supports at least C++11. Examples of such
compilers are GCC 4.7+ and Clang 3.2+.
...
...
An error occurred while installing mini_racer (0.2.9), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mini_racer -v '0.2.9' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem the link is given below :-)

https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails/issues/144

Run these lines of code

> $ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -

> $ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs